# How bitcoin peer discovery works after connecting to hard coded nodes?

Tags: bitcoin, peer, bitcoind, bitcoin-testnet, peer-discovery

I am tinkering with the bitcoin source code and trying to understand the exact working of peer discovery mechanism in the `testnet` mode for which I have made the following changes:

1. Disabled the DNS seed discovery in order to force bitcoind to fallback to connect to hardcoded nodes.
2. Changed the default hardcoded nodes to my known 4 addresses, lets say A,B,C and D, which I ensure are always online.

Now, when I run the bitcoind client (call it E), it connects to one of A,B,C or D, running the same modified version of bitcoind. It gets the peer addresses from  the hardcoded node that it first connects to by exchanging `getaddr` and `addr` messages but I am not sure how it proceeds after that. I have following queries:

a. If a node falls back to connect to hardcoded nodes, is it supposed to connect to only one of the hardcoded nodes like it happends in my case or can it connect to multiple hardcoded nodes ?

b. After getting peer address via the `addr` message, when will the node E start connecting to those peers ?

Please point me to the relevant code files/sections if possible. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

A. There are no "Hardcoded nodes" there are only DNS seeds of nodes, when you run them through the DNS request you'll get new node every request.

B. If the node isn't connected to it's maximum capacity of nodes (it's 8 active nodes and 125 inactive nodes) it will try connecting to new nodes the second it'll get the `addr` message 
you can find them here:
livenet: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/chainparams.cpp#L102 

testnet: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/chainparams.cpp#L181

Comment: There ARE hardcoded nodes. The hardcoded nodes is a backup mechanism if DNS fails. See https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/v0.13.1/src/chainparamsseeds.h